# open new screen in react native with on-press

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, button

i want to uss on press to open a new file from the button how would i go about doing that here's the file example i want to open kidsvideo.js

and here's the code for the home screen, I just can't get it to open a new window to the other file

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={kidsvideo} style={styles.panther}>
  <Image source={{uri: 'https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/avengers-assemble/images/a/a0/Usa_avengers_herochi_blackpanther_r_e1954416.png/revision/latest?cb=20170417131405'}}
   style={{width: 190, height: 300, }} />
```

Answer (score 3):

first install react-native-router-flux,if you are using npm:

```
 npm install react-native-router-flux
```

in your App.js
then import your scenes according to their files and react native router flux

```
import FirtScene from './firstscene'
import SecondScene from './secondscene
import { Actions, Router, Scene } from "react-native-router-flux";
```

then set your router in App.js

```
<Router>
    <Scene key="app">
      <Scene key="scene1" component={FirstScene} hideNavBar />
      <Scene key="scene2" component={SecondScene} hideNavBar/>
    </Scene>
</Router>
```

'scene1' will be your main screen because you put it first

then in your mainscreen ('scene1')

```
import { Actions, Router, Scene } from "react-native-router-flux";
```

and then to go from the first screen to the second:

```
TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>
            Actions.scene2()} style={styles.panther}>
```

Answer (score -1):

I don´t understand your question yet.

If you want navigate between screens, you can to use https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation

If you want routing or navigation, you can to use https://reactnavigation.org

I hope help you

Comment: Ok How do I use the button to navigate to another JavaScript file page

Comment: I want the on press button to pull up another file.js